# Highlight an image by changing opacity

Tags: html, css

I have a set of images. Whenever i hover over one i want it to be highlighted by reducing the opacity of the other images. So the image which have the cursor over it will keep its color. I tried it with the below code but it didn't work. What am i doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="first">
<img id="image1" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image2" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image3" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image4" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image5" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image6" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image7" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image8" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image9" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
<img id="image10"src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#first:hover img
{                            /* PARENT HOVER */
    opacity:0.4;  
    cursor: pointer;                    /* Dim all */
}    
#first img:hover
{                            /* SINGLE HOVER */
    opacity: 1;                /* Max one */
    color:#000000;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

Comment: Actually your code seem to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/prtdaay1/ ... Or I didn't really understand your need !

Comment: @Amine yeah wow.. It's not working in my project though.. I'll try to figure it out. Thank you

Comment: Be careful with `#first:hover img` though. It changes the opacity of images even though you are hovering the empty spaces.

Comment: you are applying css on whole div that's why effect is even before you hover on any image..trying to solve that and will tell you

Comment: @yakutsa yeah i noticed that when it worked. Any idea on how to prevent it from changing the opacity when hovering over empty spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through jQuery. Jquery is required for the below code.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#first img').hover(function() { // on mouseover
            $('#first img').css({'opacity':0.4}); // you can animate this as well
            $(this).css({'opacity':1});
        }, function() { // on mouseout
            $('#first img').css({'opacity':1});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: OP did not ask how to do in jquery so don't post this as answer please.

Comment: His solution actually works without jQuery... Check my comment on his question

Answer (score 0):

@Randy in your code,if i will hover on empty space or anywhere then it will behave like hovering on all so please check my code and let me know if it is according to your need..

In my code you will see that if you will take mouse in gap between li, still it will work..Hope i got your issue or else let me know if there is any other issue..

Thank you...

Find [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/prtdaay1/1/)

```
Code
```

Comment: Sorry to write code in end but i'm getting error while submitting the jsfiddle so i did that..hope you all understand..